# how to get knockout checkbox checked result in true or false

Tags: knockout.js

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="ifnot: Role()">
<label> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isAppAdmin"> Application Administrator </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isBusSegmentAdmin"> Business Segment Administrator </label> 
<label> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isRegionAdmin"> Region Administrator </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDivisionAdmin"> Division Administrator </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isExecutiveAdmin"> Executive Administrator </label> 
<label> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isUserAdmin"> Security Administrator </label>
<button data-bind="click: $root.create">Create</button>
</div>

function RoleViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.roleID = ko.observable("");
self.isAppAdmin = ko.observable(false);
self.isBusSegmentAdmin = ko.observable(false);
self.isRegionAdmin = ko.observable(false);
self.isDivisionAdmin = ko.observable(false);
self.isExecutiveAdmin = ko.observable(true);
self.isUserAdmin = ko.observable(false);

var Role = {
roleID: self.roleID,
isAppAdmin: self.isAppAdmin,
isBusSegmentAdmin: self.isBusSegmentAdmin,
isRegionAdmin: self.isRegionAdmin,
isDivisionAdmin: self.isDivisionAdmin,
isExecutiveAdmin: self.isExecutiveAdmin,
isUserAdmin: self.isUserAdmin
};

self.Role = ko.observable();
self.Roles = ko.observableArray();

self.create = function () {
alert(ko.toJSON(Role));

}
}
var viewModel = new RoleViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

output should like this :::: please help me out......
{"roleID":"","isAppAdmin":"fasle","isBusSegmentAdmin":"fasle","isRegionAdmin":"fasle","isDivisionAdmin":"true","isExecutiveAdmin":"true"  }

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: im always getting fasle,,, :-(

Comment: Your output from the alert is simply "false"?  You're not getting a JSON representation of the object?

Comment: Seems to be working fine in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/fbcH2/

Comment: and even works as expected in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/fbcH2/embedded/result/

Comment: @PatrickSteele . my bad luck its not working .. im getting o/p... result is always false.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps I'm wondering the problem with my checkbox design script....
I had added the few style to checkbox.. its stop to return the checked state to knockout.js...

```
$("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']").iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
});
```

Thanks for your help guys.....

Answer (score 0):

`roleID` isn't being changed because you don't have a label for it.
But if you log `viewModel.isAppAdmin()` and toggle that check-box you can see that it is changing.

I tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhAtc/